# Unity shows only admob test ads

Tags: unity, admob, unity-ads

Unity shows only admob test ads. I changed adunitId device id and removed test device but it still shows test ads real ads not shown. Please help me about the problem.

Thank you

Comment: Walk us through enough of your code and the steps you took to set up your project for us to be able to reproduce the error you're seeing in a new, empty project. Once we can reproduce your error, we can test proposed solutions to be sure that they work, so you get solid, verified answers.

Comment: Now It shows "No fill" for original ads but test ads works